# How Do I Delete Selected Item which is saved in a text file

Tags: c#, text, streamwriter

This Piece of code:

```
//Adds a user named server into the serverlist box
serverListBox.Items.Add(this.serverTextBox.Text);
//saves that user named server into a text file where the user can load the next time he/she uses the application.
string path = @"C:\\Public Key Pin\UserServerData.txt";
File.AppendAllText(path, this.serverTextBox.Text + "\n");
```

Saves the user named server (which is imputed into a Listbox) in a text file.

Now how do I delete that selected item from the text file?

Comment: Well in english words rather than code words how would you do it as a person?

Comment: You'd go into the text file and backspace it your self

Comment: Loop the serverListBox items when the application ends, overwriting the file completely.

Comment: right so you want to read all the lines and drop the one you dont want any more in code - have a go at that.

Comment: @AlexK, your idea worked!